# Given a list of values return the rows that have a column that matches the input. (EXCEL)

Tags: excel, database, filter, excel-formula

On the one hand I do have a list of users with a bunch of columns: name, email, password..... for each of them.

On the other hand I have a specific list of emails.

**What do I want to achieve?**

So basically I need to get the rows that are matching one specific column (email) with a random list of emails given. It's a big sample size so I can't search them one by one.

Example

[image]

Following this example I would need to retrieve the rows that are matching the email column with the given emails: Francis@gmail.com & Claudia@gmail.com

Comment: Check Function MATCH. Given a row/column of data, you can search a value and it will return its position inside range:

[MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)

Answer (score 1):

Use "MATCH".  Assuming your emails are in column B and the lookup values on in column E row 1, you can use the following formula:

```
=MATCH(E1,B:B,1)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(E2,$B$2:$B$5,0)),"No Match","Match")`

Result:

[image]